# Use values as new keys and assign false as the value for these in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to mutate an array that contains objects so that it contains only a key-value pair, in which the key is the value of a certain key.

Specifically, I have an input array like this:

```js
const inputArray = [
  {key1: 'en', key2: 'English'}, 
  {key1: 'ja', key2: 'Japanese', key3: 'some additional key-value-pair'}
]
```

and I would like the output array to be like this, using the values of `key2` as keys, and `false` as those values, and nothing else:

```js
const desiredOutput = [
  {English: false}, 
  {Japanese: false}
]
```

What I've tried so far is as follows, using `.map()`:

```js
const inputArray = [{key1: 'en', key2: 'English'}, {key1: 'ja', key2: 'Japanese', key3: 'some additional key-value-pair'}]

const outputArray = inputArray.map(obj => {
  obj[obj.key2] = false
  return obj
})

console.log(outputArray)
```

I tried `.reduce` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(inputArray.map((input) => {
  return {[input.key2]: false};
}));
```

```js
const inputArray = [
  {key1: 'en', key2: 'English'}, 
  {key1: 'ja', key2: 'Japanese', key3: 'some additional key-value-pair'}
]

console.log(inputArray.map((input) => {
  return {[input.key2]: false};
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing was that you were adding `key2` value to `obj` and returning that object. Instead you need to return a new object that only contain `key2` property and `false`

```js
const inputArray = [
  {key1: 'en', key2: 'English'}, 
  {key1: 'ja', key2: 'Japanese', key3: 'some additional key-value-pair'}
]

const desiredOutput=inputArray.map(obj=>(
{[obj.key2]:false}
//Here I am creating a new object and returning it
))

console.log(desiredOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

You arent morphing each element of your input array, you're adding to them....  use a new var inside the map function...

```js
const inputArray = [{
  key1: 'en',
  key2: 'English'
}, {
  key1: 'ja',
  key2: 'Japanese',
  key3: 'some additional key-value-pair'
}]

const outputArray = inputArray.map(obj => {
  let newObj = {};
  newObj[obj.key2] = false;
  return newObj;
})

console.log(outputArray);
```